# Distribute a XUL Application using Firefox binary

Tags: licensing, trademark, open-source-software

I'm going to release a XUL Application to my users. It's freeware (and maybe it will be opensource-ed later). Previously I used to package it with XULRunner and ship them all to the end user. Now I have to use `firefox -app /path/to/application.ini` instead.

However, these slight modifications are required:

1. I'd like to remove all unnecessary files and directories. Including these directories: `browser, components, defaults, dictionaries, gmp-clearkey, icons, webapprt`, and almost all `.ini` files. This is to save memory (around 18MB).
2. I want to rename `firefox`, `firefox.app` and `firefox.exe` to something else. Also, I want to change (or remove) the default firefox icon.
3. On Mac, there is an extra step. I'd like to remove 32-bit code from `XUL` library, [using `ditto` command](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050810112422666). This will save more than ~60Mb according to my tests. This is extremely useful as I don't want to have both 32-bit and 64-bit on the same bundle.

Do these modifications require Mozilla's written permission?

There is some information on this page: [Mozilla Trademark Policy](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/foundation/trademarks/policy/). However, I can't tell whether they require written permission or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this answer after contacting `trademarks AT Mozilla dot com`:

> If you are shipping a modified version of Firefox, **these steps are
>   required** :-) You may not brand it as Firefox in any way. As long as you
>   make that change, **you can make whatever other changes you want**. That's a freedom given to you by the open source licenses; you don't need our
>   permission.
>
> You will, of course, have to abide by the open source licenses governing
>   our code, for example by telling your users where to get the source code
>   of any MPLed code and Modifications. See:
>   https://www.mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/FAQ/